# I am getting java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at return (ArrayList<String[]>) query.list();

Tags: hibernate, dao

[image: 1]

In hibernate 3 version it was working fine but now I have upgraded it to hibernate version 5 and  java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer this error is coming

```
  @Override
    public ArrayList<String[]> getInvoiceDetails(
            BigInteger premiumFeeRelationshipId) {
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_START);
        sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        if(sessionFactory!=null){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        Query query = session.createQuery(BrmsCommonConstants.GETINVOICEDETAILS);
        query.setParameter(0, premiumFeeRelationshipId);
        
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_END);
        return (ArrayList<String[]>) query.list();
    }
```

> Error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be
> cast to java.lang.Integer     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:46)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.5.4.Final.jar:5.5.4.Final]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setParameter() method use **setBigInteger()** of Query interface:

```
 @Override
    public ArrayList<String[]> getInvoiceDetails(
            BigInteger premiumFeeRelationshipId) {
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_START);
        sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        if(sessionFactory!=null){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        Query query = session.createQuery(BrmsCommonConstants.GETINVOICEDETAILS);
        query.setBigInteger(0, premiumFeeRelationshipId);// instead of setParameter() method use setBigInteger here 
        
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_END);
        return (ArrayList<String[]>) query.list();
    }
```

Comment: query.setBigInteger is deprecated is there anything else I can do

Comment: Import Query from the package :  **org.hibernate.query.Query**  and make changes accordingly for **Query<R>** https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setParameter-int-java.lang.Object-org.hibernate.type.Type-

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<String[]> getInvoiceDetails(
            BigInteger premiumFeeRelationshipId) {
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_START);
        sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();
        if(sessionFactory!=null){
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        Query<?> query = session.createQuery(BrmsCommonConstants.GETINVOICEDETAILS);
        query.setParameter(0, premiumFeeRelationshipId.intValue());
        
        LOGGER.info(METHOD_END);
        return (ArrayList<String[]>) query.list();
    }
```

added .intValue() in query.setParameter(0, premiumFeeRelationshipId.intValue()); solved my problem Thank You